# Importar más de 26 campos de Excel a MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Necesito ingresar los datos de un Excel con más de 26 columnas, ejecuto el código php y no muestra ningún error, de hecho muestra todos los registros en una tabla, pero no hace la carga, es decir no se insertan en la tabla.

Comment: agrega el código Israel por favor.

Comment: añade mas información, como lo estas trabajando, saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]